# How can I treat a data column as a category and plot multiple lines?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a lot of data that has 3 parameters, pH, alkalinity and solubility calculated from the solubility:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create Data
data=[]
for i in np.arange(6,10+.1,0.1):
    pH = i
    for j in np.arange(10,110,10):
        alkalinity = j
        PO4 = 1
        solubility =  (56.68)*np.exp((-0.77)*(pH))*np.exp((-0.20)*(PO4)*(alkalinity**0.59))
        data.append([pH,alkalinity,solubility])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['pH','alkalinity','solubility'])
print(df)
```

I would like to plot this data as pH vs. Solubility (y=pH, x=solubility), but have different lines for each category of "alkalinity." Is there a simple and fast way to do this, or would I need to create a new dataframe with a column of solubility for each alkalinity and plot them individually? Here's where I'm starting from:

```
#Plot Data
fig = plt.plot(df['solubility'],df['pH'])
plt.xlabel('Solubility mg/L')
plt.ylabel('pH')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if you need to do with data frame,you could do in this way:

```
for value in np.arange(10,110,10):
  pH=df[df['alkalinity'] == value]['pH']
  solubility =df[df['alkalinity'] == value]['solubility']
  plt.plot(solubility, pH)

plt.legend(labels=[f"alkalinity = {a}" for a in np.arange(10,110,10)])
plt.xlabel("solubility");
plt.ylabel("pH")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using pandas,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pH = np.arange(6,10+.1,0.1)
alkalinity = np.arange(10,110,10)
PO4 = 1

alkalinity, pH = np.meshgrid(alkalinity, pH)
solubility =  (56.68)*np.exp((-0.77)*(pH))*np.exp((-0.20)*(PO4)*(alkalinity**0.59))

plt.plot(solubility, pH)
plt.legend(labels=[f"alkalinity = {a}" for a in alkalinity[0]])
plt.xlabel("solubility"); plt.ylabel("pH")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That is really cool and helpful, but I'm not sure it's a great solution for my actual needs The reason I am using a loop is because later on I call a function from another file that runs a much more complex solubility calculation with several intermediate calculations that I also add onto the DataFrame. I'll play around with this meshgrid anyway because I may be able to rewerite the complex function to work around it with some effort. Thanks!